# Golang accessing parent package values in child package

Tags: go, interface

Hello i think i am running into an interface/struct problem. I know go doesn't support inheritance and im kind of stomp on figuring this `import cycle not allowed` bug.

In my actual code I have defined a struct inside `pkg A` that I want to access in `pkg C` . Im seeing i should use interfaces to accomplish this but I don't know how I should do this.
For example  I have something like
`pkg A` is the parent
`pkg B` is the child
pkg C` is another child

````
import pkg B

B.test1() // accessing method from pkg B


pkg B

import pkg C
import pkg A

C.test2() // accessing method from pkg C

pkg C
import pkg A
// This results in a import cycle error
A.Field1 // Trying to access a struct value from the parent package```
````

Comment: There is not a parent/child relationship between packages in Go.

Comment: Just stop making tiny packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency graph described by package imports must be acyclic, hence the "import cycle not allowed" error message you're encountering.

If, for instance, package `Alpha` imports package `Bravo` and package `Bravo` imports package `Charlie`, package `Charlie` can't import package `Alpha` (or `Bravo` for that matter) because that would introduce a cycle into the dependency graph.

The shared dependency(ies) need to be refactored into another package so as to eliminate the cycle. In my above example, you might refactor package `Alpha` and extract the bits that both it and package `Charlie` need into a new package `Delta` that gets imported by both `Alpha` and `Charlie`.